# populate cells with VBA using cell names with excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I hope someone can help me, but I need to populate cells with data from sharepoint.

All is working OK with the following part of VB script

```
If metaprop.Name = "Revision" Then
    Cells(2, 18).Value = metaprop.Value
End If
```

this puts the "revision" data into the cell on row 2, column 18.

My issue is that if anyone changes the speadsheet by adding columns between column 1 & 18 then the data gets entered in the wrong cell!

Is there a way of referencing the cell using cell names?
and if so can you tell me the correct syntax?

Many Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as follows:

```
Range("myRangeName").Value = metaprop.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheet1.Range("YourRangeNameHere")
```